# Next Auth middleware export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"; not working

Tags: reactjs, middleware, next.js13, next-auth

I'm currently working on a project using Next.js 13 (version **13.4.19**) and I've integrated NextAuth.js (version **^4.23.1**) for authentication. I'm trying to use the `next-auth/middleware` module to secure a specific route in my application, but I'm encountering an issue with the middleware configuration.

I wanted only **export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";**
on my **/middleware.ts**.
Im using app directory and my middleware.ts located at the root folder same level of app folder.

Here's my code:

```
// /middleware.ts

export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
    //code below works when added
    //export const config = {matcher: ["/dashboard"]}; // this works fine but when I've tried with an empty config it dosen't work
```

[image]

---

this is my **/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts**

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

const handler: NextAuthOptions = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          // Replace with the actual endpoint URL
          const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          });

          if (res.ok) {
            const user = await res.json();
            if (user) {
              return Promise.resolve(user);
            }
          }

          return Promise.resolve(null);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Authentication error:", error);
          return Promise.resolve(null);
        }
      },
    }),
    // Other authentication providers, if any
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**here is the URL on error**

http://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin%3FcallbackUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flogin%253FcallbackUrl%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Flogin%25253FcallbackUrl%25253Dhttp%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Flogin%2525253FcallbackUrl%2525253Dhttp%252525253A%252525252F%252525252Flocalhost%252525253A3000%252525252Flogin%252525253FcallbackUrl%252525253Dhttp%25252525253A%25252525252F%25252525252Flocalhost%25252525253A3000%25252525252Flogin%25252525253FcallbackUrl%25252525253Dhttp%2525252525253A%2525252525252F%2525252525252Flocalhost%2525252525253A3000%2525252525252Flogin%2525252525253FcallbackUrl%2525252525253Dhttp%252525252525253A%252525252525252F%252525252525252Flocalhost%252525252525253A3000%252525252525252Flogin%252525252525253FcallbackUrl%252525252525253Dhttp%25252525252525253A%25252525252525252F%25252525252525252Flocalhost%25252525252525253A3000%25252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525253FcallbackUrl%25252525252525253Dhttp%2525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252Flocalhost%2525252525252525253A3000%2525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%2525252525252525253Dhttp%252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252Flocalhost%252525252525252525253A3000%252525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%252525252525252525253Dhttp%25252525252525252525253A%25252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252Flocalhost%25252525252525252525253A3000%25252525252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%25252525252525252525253Dhttp%2525252525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252Flocalhost%2525252525252525252525253A3000%2525252525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%2525252525252525252525253Dhttp%252525252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252Flocalhost%252525252525252525252525253A3000%252525252525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%252525252525252525252525253Dhttp%25252525252525252525252525253A%25252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525252Flocalhost%25252525252525252525252525253A3000%25252525252525252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%25252525252525252525252525253Dhttp%2525252525252525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525252Flocalhost%2525252525252525252525252525253A3000%2525252525252525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253Dhttp%252525252525252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252525252Flocalhost%252525252525252525252525252525253A3000%252525252525252525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253Dhttp%25252525252525252525252525252525253A%25252525252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525252525252Flocalhost%25252525252525252525252525252525253A3000%25252525252525252525252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FcallbackUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253Dhttp%2525252525252525252525252525252525253A%2525252525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Flocalhost%2525252525252525252525252525252525253A3000%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Fwelcome

Answer (score 1):

```
I had the same problems.
I have fixed it by:

    <code>
     import { type NextRequestWithAuth, withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

     const middleware = async (request: NextRequestWithAuth) => {
       // your middleware function logic
     };

     export const config = {
      matcher: ['/'],
     };

     export default withAuth(middleware);
    </code>


  <code>
// options.ts
    import { type AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
    import { prisma } from '@/dbClient/client';
    import type { User } from '@prisma/client';
    import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
    import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
    import { compare } from 'bcrypt';
    export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        id: 'credentials',
        name: 'credentials',
        credentials: {
          email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
          password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
        },
        authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
          if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) return null;

          const user: User | null = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
              email: credentials.email,
            },
          });

          if (!user) return null;

          const doesPasswordMatch = await compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        if (!doesPasswordMatch) return null;
        console.log({ user }, { credentials }, { req });
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],

  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  callbacks: {},
};
</code>
```

Comment: Please mention how your code fixes the problem rather than providing a wall of code.

Comment: You need to know how to use features from next auth for middleware of next js. The first pice of code is right about middleware and how I have implemented it. But what I have understand from next auth is that if will miss at list some minor variable which should be exported and you didn't, it will not work, and to find correct info in docs not really possible without know where to find. So that's why I have shown practically the whole implementation of my pet project for middleware and credential provider.